# How do I format these nested loops in Java?

Tags: java, nested-loops, alphabetical

[The Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPfu2.jpg)

Hello! I am trying to learn how to use nested for loops in AP Computer Science at school, and I am having trouble with this lab :/ I have made some progress towards getting the correct result. However, I am having issues on my path. The image above shows what I need to do.

Sample Data:

> C 4
>
> A 5
>
> Sample Output:
>
> CCCC DDD EE F
>
> CCCC DDD EE
>
> CCCC DDD
>
> CCCC

---

> AAAAA BBBB CCC DD E
>
> AAAAA BBBB CCC DD
>
> AAAAA BBBB CCC
>
> AAAAA BBBB
>
> AAAAA

also above is the I/O I need.

The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LettersAndNumbers {
    public static void main(String args []) {
    int times;
    String character;//I know this sounds stupid
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a character and integer");
    character = scan.nextLine();
    times = scan.nextInt();

    String output ="";
    for(int i=times; i>=0;i--) {
        for(int j=i;j>=1;j--){
            for(int x = j; x>=1; x--)
            {
                output=output + character;


            }
            output=output+" ";

        }           
        output=output +'\n';
        int charValue = character.charAt(0);
        character = String.valueOf( (char) (charValue + 1));    
    }
    System.out.println(output);
  }
}
```

It yields the following output (I'm getting close):

Enter a character and integer C

> 4
>
> CCCC CCC CC C
>
> DDD DD D
>
> EE E
>
> F

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInputChar=scanner.next();
    char userChar=userInputChar.charAt(0);      
    int userInputDigit=scanner.nextInt();       
    for(int i=1;i<=userInputDigit;i++){
        char charProcess=userChar;          
        for(int j=(userInputDigit-i)+1,l=userInputDigit;j>=1;j--,l--){              
            for(int k=l;k>=1;k--){
                System.out.print(charProcess);
            }
            charProcess=(char) (charProcess+1);
            System.out.print(" ");              
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    scanner.close();
```

Let me know how it goes. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

For the scanner, I would use useDelimiter("\s")  (meaning split on spaces) and next() to get the character and int out for the string. I'll leave this for you to figure out on your own.
For the loop part of it. Assuming you have a starting character and times. You can print

```
for(int i = times; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
         int numRepeats = i - j;
         String output = "";
         String repeatedCharacter = String.valueOf(startingCharacter + j);
         for(int k = 0; k < numRepeats; k++){
             output += repeatedCharacter;
         }
         System.out.print(output + " ");
    }
     System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are two hints:

1) `character = String.valueOf( (char) (charValue + 1));`
Maybe see if there's a better place for this statement?

2) Perhaps you can use something for the variable 'character' other than String...

Good luck!